# How to get Saakshatkaram of lord Sri Lakshmi Narayana?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi

How to get Saakshatkaram of lord Sri Lakshmi Narayana and darshanam of Sri Moksha dhama Sri Vaikuntam?

Answer (score 1):

For Bhagavat-sakshatkara, our scriptures prescribes (i) japa of Mantra given by a Siddha-Guru --such ShAkti or ShAmbhavi diksha does not need purascharana, (ii) purascharana of Mantra given by Guru obeying Guru's guidance, (iii) Single-minded devotion and chanting of NAma of God.

Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath writes in this regard

> God does not give darshan unless all sins are washed off. He gives boon at the time of giving darshan. All the three types of suffereing ends for ever, the devotee is immersed in samadhi.

The vision of the Vaikunthadhama can be asked as a boon.

He also writes

> Tears of Joy, extreme bliss -these are symptoms of the Mantra-chaitanya as per Tantra.Learn the meaning of the Mantra, Mantra-chaitanya and yoni-mudra from your Guru and do Purascharana."niskAmAnAm anenyaiva sakshatkarah bhavati-- **the desireless persons gets the vision of God by these.**

Regarding the process of the Purascharana, the Kularnava-Tantra writes:

> japa-homou tarpanam cha avishekau vipra-bhojanam/homo brahmamabhuktis cha purascharanam uchchyate//, meaning the purascharana consists of japa, homa, tarpana, avisheka, and feeding the brahmins.(Kularnava-Tantra,15/8).

The Meru-Tantra writes

> japo homas tarpanam cha marjanam viprabhojanam/panchAngakarmarupam tad Ahuh kechana tatra tu// meaning that Purascharana consists of japa, homa, tarpana, mArjana and feeding  the brahmins.

There are details of Dasa-Anga Purascharana in Kaulavalinirnaya-Tantra.All these must be learned from an able Guru.

Chanting the mantra or nAma with devotion can also give siddhi:

> japAt siddhir japAt siddhir japAt siddhir na sanshayah

According to Sri Ramakrishna,

> When one becomes very eager and restless to see God, just as a person being dipped in a river pangs for breath, He gets the vision of God.In the age of kali, if one sheds tears for just for one whole day and night being restless to see God, he/she can get darshan of God.

(Reference: 1.Sastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana,mUpendrakumar Das, RMIC, vol 2, page 767-8). 2. Omkarnath Rachanavali, Mahamilan Math, vol 1, page 178-182. 3.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Kathamrita, Sri M, Udbodhan edition.

Answer (score 1):

Srimad Bhagavatm 1.2.7

vāsudeve bhagavati

bhakti-yogaḥ prayojitaḥ

janayaty āśu vairāgyaṁ

jñānaṁ ca yad ahaitukam

, Śī ṛṣṇ,          .

Padma Purana

ataḥ śrī-kṛṣṇa-nāmādi

na bhaved grāhyam indriyaiḥ

sevonmukhe hi jihvādau

svayam eva sphuraty ada

"    ṛṣṇ   ,       . ,       ,                   ."

Srimad Bhagavatam 12.3.51, 52

krte yad dhyayato visnum

tretayam yajato makhaih

dvapare paricaryayam

kalau tad dhari-kirtanat

"     -    ,  -   ,   -    ’       -      '  ."

kaler doṣa-nidhe rājann

asti hy eko mahān guṇaḥ

kīrtanād eva kṛṣṇasya

mukta-saṅgaḥ paraṁ vrajet

"  ,  -     ,         :     '   ,              ."

Kali-santarana Upanisad from Krishna Yajur Veda:-

krishna hare krishna krishna krishna hare hare

hare rama hare rama rama rama hare hare

iti sodasakam namnam kali-kalmasa-nasanam

natah parataropayah sarva-vedesu drsyate

"       -:        ,                 .        ."

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [Ramakishna Paramhamsa](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ramakrishna) and many other previous saints like Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and all the Puranas, **that for Kaliyuga, Bhakti alone is the way.**

> **Can you weep for Him with intense longing of heart? Men shed a jugful
>   of tears  for the sake of their children, for their wives, or for
>   money. But who weeps for God?** So long as the child remains engrossed
>   with its toys, the mother looks after her cooking and other household
>   duties. But when the child no longer relishes the toys, it throws them
>   aside and yells for its mother. Then the mother takes the rice-pot
>   down from the hearth, runs in haste, and takes the child in her arms.
>
> **Lovers of God do not belong to any caste. … A brāhmin without this
>   love is no longer a brāhmin. And a pariah with the love of God is no
>   longer a pariah. Through bhakti an untouchable becomes pure and
>   elevated.**
>
> You see many stars in the sky at night, but not when the sun rises.
>   Can you therefore say that there are no stars in the heavens during
>   the day? **O man, because you cannot find God in the days of your
>   ignorance, say not that there is no God.**
>
> He is born in vain, who having attained the human birth, so difficult
>   to get, does not attempt to realize God in this very life
>
> **Little children play with dolls in the outer room just as they like,
>   without any care of fear or restraint; but as soon as their mother
>   comes in, they throw aside their dolls and run to her crying, "Mamma,
>   mamma." You too, are now playing in this material world, infatuated
>   with the dolls of wealth, honour, fame, etc., If however, you once see
>   your Divine Mother, you will not afterwards find pleasure in all
>   these. Throwing them all aside, you will run to her.**

Comment: i was just about to post from RK's sayings - there is another one about disciple plunged into water, can u post that

Comment: @ram add your answer too than

Comment: i want to avoid very similar answers